# Is there a way to run freely available systemverilog testbenches on osx

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, system-verilog

I'm trying to run some testbenches for Systemverilog on OSX Yosemite (10.10.3). The only free simulators I know of that I can use are Verilator, which cannot handle testbenches, and Icarus, which apparently handles "very little" SystemVerilog. Are there any I can use on a mac to run SystemVerilog testbenches?

Answer (score 0):

You can, with a Windows emulator.

None of the "free" simulators support constrained random generation, assertions, or functional coverage for testbenches.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to go web-based, [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com) has the educational version of Riviera-PRO available which has full SystemVerilog support.

The "free" version of Modelsim provided by the [Altera toolchain](http://dl.altera.com/?edition=web) is limited but can run UVM with some caveats.  From the old [EDA Playground docs](https://github.com/edaplayground/eda-playground/blob/7cd59f87389aa66e9c4da36b89e814bed2369ada/docs/modelsim-uvm.rst):

> UVM can be used with ModelSim 10.1d as long as the following coding style adjustments are followed:
>
> When creating a uvm_sequence, put the following in the constructor: `do_not_randomize = 1'b1`;
>
> ```
> class my_sequence extends uvm_sequence #(my_transaction);
>
> function new();
>   // MUST BE SET when using ModelSim
>   do_not_randomize = 1'b1;
> endfunction
> ```